# Calculating change in percent of the properties in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to calculate the percent change for a range of data by it's prior range.

Here's an example of what I'm working on:

Below is an array of objects that I need to calculate a percent change for `displayAd_imp`, `videoAd_imp`, and `tv_impbased` properties based on a selection of `WeekNo` range.

```
var objArr = [{

    "Title": "July 13 - July 19 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "3,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "1.5",
        "tv_imp": "0.52",
        "Date": "2014-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 29
}, {

    "Title": "July 20 - July 26 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,600",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.55",
        "tv_imp": "0.052",
        "Date": "2014-07-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 30
}, {

    "Title": "July 27 - Aug 2 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.1",
        "tv_imp": "0.122",
        "Date": "2014-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 31
}, {

    "Title": "Aug 3 - Aug 9 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,500",
        "videoAd_imp": "1.99",
        "tv_imp": "0.254",
        "Date": "2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 32
}, {

    "Title": "Aug 10 - Aug 17 2014",
        "displayAd_imp": "1,400",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.0",
        "tv_imp": ".235",
        "Date": "2014-08-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "WeekNo": 33
}];
```

In the method below I'm trying to achieve this task by first filtering the data with start and end `WeekNo`, then calculating the sum of that data. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k97LLwju/1/) working example.

```
function CalcWeekRange(data,begin,end){
    //console.log(data,begin, end);
    var newArr = data.filter(function(item){
        return (item.WeekNo >= begin && item.WeekNo <= end);
    });

    var sumArr = [newArr.reduce(function (acc, x) {
        Object.keys(acc).forEach(function (k) {
        acc[k] += Number(x[k]);
                });
                return acc;
            }, {
                displayAd_imp: 0,
                videoAd_imp: 0,
                tv_imp: 0,
            })];
            console.log(sumArr);
}
```

The part I'm having difficulty with is calculating the percent change for that period by getting the sum of previous range and then current/previous - 1. So for example, in the above jsfiddle we called `CalcWeekRange(objArr,32,33);`.

The percent change logic for `displayAd_imp`would be:

Current Weeks(32,33): 1400+1500 = 2900 (We have this part in `sumArr`)

Previous Weeks(30,31): 1600+1500 = 3100

%Change: (2900/3100-1)*100 = **-6.45** (Note: negative is allowed)

The above would happen for the rest of the properties as well.

Hopefully the question and examples are clear, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this in addition to your above object array and code?

```
var jCurrent = CalcWeekRange(objArr,32,33);
var jPrevious = CalcWeekRange(objArr,30,31);
var jCurrentDisplay = jCurrent[0].displayAd_imp;
var jPreviousDisplay = jPrevious[0].displayAd_imp;
var result = (jCurrentDisplay/jPreviousDisplay-1)*100;
console.log("result ", result);
```

Adjusted your jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/zd2ok8qq/)

Update: In case you want to get the results based on the actual current week, this can be done with following adjustment to above code:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
 var firstday = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
 var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate());
 var dayOfYear = ((today - firstday + 86400000)/86400000);
 return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7)
};

var today = new Date();
var currentWeekNumber = today.getWeek();

var jCurrentDynamic = CalcWeekRange(objArr,currentWeekNumber-1,currentWeekNumber);
var jPreviousDynamic = CalcWeekRange(objArr,currentWeekNumber -3,currentWeekNumber -2);

var jCurrentDisplayDynamic = jCurrentDynamic[0].displayAd_imp;
var jPreviousDisplayDynamic = jPreviousDynamic[0].displayAd_imp;
var resultDynamic = (jCurrentDisplayDynamic/jPreviousDisplayDynamic-1)*100;
console.log("resultDynamic ", resultDynamic);
```

I've updated the fiddle and added an object for the actual current week number 34 (just a copy of week 33 for testing), so the fiddle will stop working next week :)

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/rmakxf6r/)

Comment: Thanks for adjusting the jsfiddle, is there a way to calculate it dynamically? I like the way you did it but start and end params will be coming from a drop-down field so we before calling the function again with new params we need to check for week range and then call the function again for the prior weeks.

Comment: @user3061445 Glad to hear that it goes in the right direction. Sure it's possible to have it dynamically, just need some further input - the current week is always the last entry in the dropdown / array? Without knowing the amount of objects in your array I would have to take a guess. Or is it necessary to get the current week, e.g. using date-functions, to know which object to choose for getting the current range?

Comment: I don't think we need whole data object posted here on SO.

Comment: @TomášZato Yes sorry you're right, thanks for the advice. Just edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k97LLwju/3/ - This is what I was shooting for, it's not the most prettiest way of doing it but gets the job done. Thanks for the ideas!