# Working with JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Is there an efficient way to calculate percent change for each key in an object?

The formula is `(x/y-1)*100` -  the `x` being `arry[0].key` and `y` is `arry[1].key`.

For example below is an array of objects that I would like to apply the formula above and return another object with percent changes.

```
var objArr = [{

        "displayAd_imp": "3500",
        "videoAd_imp": "1.5",
        "tv_imp": "0.52"
}, {
        "displayAd_imp": "1600",
        "videoAd_imp": "2.55",
        "tv_imp": "0.052"
}]
```

An example of the calculation would be

```
objArr[0].displayAd_imp / objArr[1].displayAd_imp - 1)*100 //this returns -3.74
```

and the data in the object would be `{displayAd_imp_c : -3.74}`

I'm not sure if looping both the object at the same time is a good idea, but I couldn't find a good way to loop through the keys and calculate the formula for each.

Hope I'm being clear on this, thanks for reading!

Comment: See [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/85992/218196)

Comment: I guess this is the follow up question from your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437327/calculating-change-in-percent-of-the-properties-in-javascript-objects ?

Comment: Yes right, I got down to two objects from calculating the week ranges and getting their sum. I just need to apply the formula now and that should give me what I need. Thanks for following the questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
objArr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (index > 0) {
    item.displayAd_imp_c = (objArr[index-1].displayAd_imp / (item.displayAd_imp - 1) * 100;
  }
});
```

would probably do it in place. Not the prettiest solution, but reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! I like the way your doing the calculation, although we just need an index for the second item -